# Cannot create Vagrant machine on windows 7 computer

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have a Windows 7 computer with VirtualBox, Vagrant, Docker Toolbox and Git. VirtualBox displays a machine named "default" (created during Docker installation) to which I can connect using command C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh".

So far so good.

I made a local copy of a repo which has a Vagrantfile in it and is supposed to create a few Vagrant machines: https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook

I ran the command:

```
$vagrant up --no-parallel

Bringing machine 'web' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'spark' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'es' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'redis' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'scrapyd1' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'scrapyd2' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'scrapyd3' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'dev' up with 'docker' provider...
==> web: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
```

and then it hangs forever. Another try:

```
$ vagrant up --no-parallel --debug
```

The result is a very long output (with no "error" or "warning" string in it). It ends with the following:

```
...
DEBUG environment: Default provider: `docker`
 INFO loader: Set :root = ["#<Pathname:J:/Projects.temp/scrapybook/Vagrantfile.dockerhost>"]
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:J:/Projects.temp/scrapybook/Vagrantfile.dockerhost>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: J:/Projects.temp/scrapybook/Vagrantfile.dockerhost
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (evaluating)
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
DEBUG push: finalizing
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0/powershell.EXE", "-NoLogo", "-NoProfile", "-NonInteractive", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command", "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 2
```

and it hangs forever from here.

```
$vagrant status
web                       not created (docker)
spark                     not created (docker)
es                        not created (docker)
redis                     not created (docker)
mysql                     not created (docker)
scrapyd1                  not created (docker)
scrapyd2                  not created (docker)
scrapyd3                  not created (docker)
dev                       not created (docker)
```

The above command works correctly but the following hangs with no output at all:

```
$ vagrant status web
```

I have no experience with Vagrant or Docker, just wanted to run some code from this repo. How to install these Vagrant machines?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to upgrade the version of powershell installed on your machine. Here is one of such issue reported and fix for it https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/7823